# How to make PlayerView full screen in landscape mode when used in MotionLayout

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-motionlayout

I want to make it possible to make the PlayerView in landscape mode full screen but I can't make it work. So far, I have tried to set the playerView layout params programmatically when configuration changes to landscape mode, but it still isn't working.

Layout that I have created

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/player_motion_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/vod_player_scene"
    app:viewToDetectTouch="@id/top_player_container">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_player_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:background="#272727"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_playback_control_view_vod"
        app:fastforward_increment="10000"
        app:hide_on_touch="true"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:resize_mode="fixed_width"
        app:rewind_increment="10000"
        app:show_timeout="2000" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/playerView" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/top_player_container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image_clear"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/top_player_container"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_32dp"
        app:tint="@color/white" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/top_player_container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/top_player_container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/top_player_container"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clear_32dp"
        app:tint="@color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/video_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semi_bold"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/top_player_container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image_play"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/top_player_container"
        tools:text="Blade Runner" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/video_club_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_player_container" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_front"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/video_club_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_player_container" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_progressView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/recyclerview_front"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/recyclerview_front"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/recyclerview_front" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

And programatically, I am doing it this way (see below code)

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        int newOrientation = newConfig.orientation;

        if (newOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            MotionLayout.LayoutParams params = (MotionLayout.LayoutParams)
                    getPlayerView().getLayoutParams();
            params.width = params.MATCH_PARENT;
            params.height = params.MATCH_PARENT;
            getPlayerView().setLayoutParams(params);
        } else {

        }
    }
```

Also in Manifest.xml I have declared activity as

```
    <activity
         android:name=".main.MainActivity"       
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Let me know if you need anything else to share with you.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to change any of the views that have `MotionLayout` as parent, we should work with `MotionScene`.

What I did to fix this problem, I created two functions, one to make `playerView` **width** and **height** to `MATCH_PARENT` and the other to reset it to previous state (when screen orientation back to portrait).

```
private void setPlayerToMatchHeight() {
    ConstraintSet expandedSet = getMotionLayout().getConstraintSet(R.id.expanded);
    ConstraintSet.Constraint topPlayerContainerSet = expandedSet.getConstraint(R.id.top_player_container);
    topPlayerContainerSet.layout.mHeight = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
}

private void setPlayerTo16x9dimensionRatio() {
    ConstraintSet expandedSet = getMotionLayout().getConstraintSet(R.id.expanded);
    ConstraintSet.Constraint topPlayerContainerSet = expandedSet.getConstraint(R.id.top_player_container);
    topPlayerContainerSet.layout.mHeight = 0;
    topPlayerContainerSet.layout.dimensionRatio = "16:9";
}
```

And then, in `onConfigurationChanged`, based on newOrientation, I call these functions respectively.